# Help with test class on

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I need help to get more code coverage for the test class but I'm not sure how to approach it

Class:

```
 public  class salesforcetoJiraHandler  {

   public static void newmed ( List<Internal_Request__c> triggerNew, Map<ID,Internal_Request__c> mapNew, Map<ID,Internal_Request__c> mapOld){
    
        Jira_credential__mdt g = Jira_credential__mdt.getInstance('Admin');
        String obname = g.Fieldset1__c; 
        String FS = g.Fieldset2__c;
    
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(obname);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(FS);
    
    
        list<String> fieldSetAPI = new list<string>();
        map<string,string> apiVslabelMap = new map<string,string>();
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : fieldSetObj.getFields())
        {
            fieldSetAPI.add(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath());
            apiVslabelMap.put(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath(),fieldSetMemberObj.getLabel());
            system.debug('API Name ====>' + fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath()); 
        }
    
            Boolean its = false;
            for(ID Mapid: mapNew.keyset()){
    
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMemberObj : fieldSetObj.getFields()) {
    
            if (string.valueOF(mapOld.get(Mapid).get(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath())) != string.valueOF(mapNew.get(Mapid).get(fieldSetMemberObj.getFieldPath())))  
            {
                its = true;
                
            }
            } 
        }
    
        if(its == true){
            checkStatus(triggerNew);
        }
    
       }
    
        
            public static void checkStatus (List<Internal_Request__c> IRT){
                List<ID> InRIds = new List <ID>();
                for(Internal_Request__c ir : (IRT)){
                    InRIds.add(ir.Id);
        
                }
                changeStatus(InRIds); 
                system.debug('What the trigger is sending: '+InRIds); 
                
               }
        
          
           @future(callout = true)
           public static void changeStatus(List<Id> irsID){ 
    
            List<Internal_Request__c> workR = [SELECT CreatedById, ID, key__c, Status_IR__c FROM Internal_Request__c WHERE ID IN :irsID];
                system.debug('What are we getting: ' +workR[0].Status_IR__c);
    
                
            String Status =  workR[0].Status_IR__c;
            String id =  workR[0].ID;
            String Cby = workR[0].CreatedById;
            
            system.debug(Status); 
            system.debug(id); 
           
                
            Map<String, Stat_Salesforce_to_Jira__mdt> ics = Stat_Salesforce_to_Jira__mdt.getAll();
            Map<String,Decimal> str = new Map <String, Decimal>();
            for (Stat_Salesforce_to_Jira__mdt vr : ics.values()) {
                  str.put(vr.Salesforce_Status__c, vr.Jira_Status_Id__c);
            }
          
                if(str.containskey(Status)){
                   
                 
    
                    Jira_credential__mdt globalmc = Jira_credential__mdt.getInstance('Admin');
        
                    string username = globalmc.Username__c;
                    string password = globalmc.Password__c; // is the security token from Atlassian account profile --> Manage your Account-->Security-->API token-->Create and manage API tokens--> Manage your account-->API tokens
                    
                    String url1 = globalmc.SalesforcetoJira_Url__c;
                    String url2 = globalmc.SalesforcetoJira_Url2__c;
                    
                    
                    
                    String auth_header = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password));
        
                    String url = url1+workR[0].key__c+url2;
        
                        Http http = new Http();
                        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
                        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
                        req.setHeader('Authorization', auth_header);
                        req.setHeader('X-Atlassian-Token', 'nocheck');
                        req.setMethod('POST');
                        req.setEndpoint(url);
                        req.setBody('{ "transition": { "id": "'+str.get(Status)+'"}}');
    
                        try{
                            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                            system.debug(res);
                            
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            system.debug('Error: ' + e);
                        }
                
            }
          
            
           }         
    }
```

- TEST Classes

HttpCalloutMock

```
 @isTest
global class JiraInsertMockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock  {
   global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response 
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "test" }, "summary": "test", "issuetype": { "name": "test" },  "description": "test" } }');
    
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
    }
}
```

Test for the class

```
@isTest
public class salesforcetoJiratest {
    public static testmethod void testsalesfortojiraHandler(){
     List<Internal_Request__c> testC = new List<Internal_Request__c>{new Internal_Request__C(Concerned_App__c ='Business test',     Type__c = 'test', 
                                                                                                Priority__c = 'Medium', Subject__c = 'test', Description__c = 'test',
                                                                                              Project_Name__c = 'test', Jira_Type__c = 'bug', URL_Jira__c = 'www.test.com',
                                                                                              Key__c = 'test',  Status_IR__c = 'Acknowledge', Jira_Key__c = 'test', 
                                                                                                Jira_Status__c = 'In Development' )};
                                                                                                    
       insert testC;
       
        
        
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setBody('{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "test" }, "summary": "test", "issuetype": { "name": "test" },  "description": "test" } }');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        
        test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new JiraInsertMockHttpResponseGenerator());
        
        
        Test.startTest();
        Internal_Request__c tstITR = new Internal_Request__c();
        salesforcetoJiraHandler.checkStatus(testC);
        Test.stopTest();   
    }
}
```

For the moment I'm getting 34% of coverage but I'm not sure how to do it, any help or advice to get more code coverage?:

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thing, add a unit test for every public method of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the coverage report, it looks like the "newmed" method is being run - where is that method being called from and with what trigger context?
Is your test method completing it's run or failing? Some more detail will assist.

EDIT: Validation of allowed values for a picklist still occurs when inserting data from a test class, so you'll need to update that first. Then, as the first comment on your post mentions, you should write a unit test for each public method in your class. To get coverage for the trigger portion of the class, write a test that updates an Internal_Request__c record that meets the logic for calling your code.

Comment: the newmed method  is being used after an update from after update trigger                       `trigger trigger_Jira on Internal_Request__c (after update) {
    if (trigger.isUpdate && !System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch()) {
        jira_Insert.issueCU(Trigger.New); 
          salesforcetoJiraHandler.newmed(Trigger.new, trigger.newMap , trigger.oldMap);   
    }  
    
}`

Comment: it run but display that is failing

Comment: Can you paste the failure message?

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Status IR: bad value for restricted picklist field: Acknowledge: [Status_IR__c]

Comment: That's a pretty straight forward error - is 'Acknowledge' an allowed value for the "Status_IR__c" picklist field?

Comment: Yes, it is an allowed value for the picklist, but I tried with all the values from the picklist and it still gave me the same error

Comment: Does the object have any record types? This article gives a detailed breakdown of possible causes for this error: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320321&type=1

Comment: Now that you mention in the custom object we managed two record types, and I think I need to add the record type when I insert the test data, I will try to add the record type that needs a specific value, I thought since is a test to an HTTPCallout it was not necessary to perform it, also it's necessary to use update when I'm inserting the test data since the first method is expecting, trigger new, old map and new map?

Comment: Validation of allowed values for a picklist still occurs when inserting data from a test class, so you'll need to update that first. Then, as the first comment on your post mentions, you should write a unit test for each public method in your class. To get coverage for the trigger portion of the class, write a test that updates an Internal_Request__c record that meets the logic for calling your code.

Comment: @Felix van Hove
Thank You both for the tips, I was able to get 97% for code coverage